# Phing: replace token with file or multiline value?

Tags: build, phing

I have a file `ga-code.txt` which contains analytics code.
I want to use `phing` in a build to replace this token `@ga-code@` in `index.php` with the contents of `ga-code.txt`

Is this possible with `phing`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can do it with Phing's replacetokenswithfile

The following would replace html comment `<!--@@ga-code@@-->` with the contents of a file named `ga-code.txt`

```
<replacetokenswithfile begintoken="&lt;!--@@" endtoken="@@--&gt;" dir="${builddir}/production/" postfix=".txt" translatehtml="false" />
```